# Access Javascript object - Scope issue with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'd like to fetch mail from a mailbox regularly using a Node daemon. The call to the connection method is made in `app.js`.

The javascript file I use to connect to my mailbox (`mail.js`):

```
var imap = new Imap({
    user: 'xxxx@hotmail.com',
    password: config.get.gmail_password,
    host: 'xxxxx',
    port: 993,
    tls: true
});

var fetchMail = function()
{
    console.log('Connection');
    imap.connect();
};

//fetchMail();

imap.once('ready', function() {
   console.log('Ready'); 

   imap.search([ 'UNSEEN', ['FROM', 'xxxx'] ], function(err, results)
   {
       // Do Stuff
   }

exports.fetchMail = fetchMail;
```

If I use `fetchMail()` directly from `mail.js`, everything is fine.

However, when I try to call it from `app.js`:

```
var mail = require('./js/mail');
mail.fetchMail()
```

Then, the method stay in the `fetchMail()` function from `mail.js` and the `imap.once('ready', function())`is never triggered.

I guess it is a scope issue with the `imap` var in `mail.js`.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**

I solved this in a way I don't like. I wrote everything's related to the imap var inside the `fecthMail()`function.

Please, do not hesitate to write a more efficient answer to this.

Comment: Did you tried `module.exports = fetchMail;` in `mail.js` ?

Comment: Yes but `fetchMail is not a function` in `app.js`.

Comment: Not in `app.js`, you need to first export from `mail.js` then use it `app.js` by doing `require`

Comment: Yep. That's what I've done :)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to bind the event every time you connect. So like so:

```
var fetchMail = function()
{
    console.log('Connection');

    imap.once('ready', function() {
      console.log('Ready');         
      imap.search([ 'UNSEEN', ['FROM', 'xxxx'] ], function(err, results)
      {
        // Do Stuff
      }
    }
    imap.connect();
};
```

Comment: Thanks ! I still am blocked in the connection phase. It would also help me if you could may be explain a bit your solution ? :)

Answer (score 0):

The approach and idea is great. All you need is to change the syntax of mail.js file to return a module. In another words when you do

`var mail = require('./js/mail');`

what do you expect to be in the mail variable?

You might need to change logic around, but try this:

```
var MailHandler = function () {}

var imap = new Imap({
    user: 'xxxx@hotmail.com',
    password: config.get.gmail_password,
    host: 'xxxxx',
    port: 993,
    tls: true
});

MailHandler.init = function(){
  imap.once('ready', function() {
     console.log('Ready'); 

     imap.search([ 'UNSEEN', ['FROM', 'xxxx'] ], function(err, results)
     {
         // Do Stuff
     }
  }
}

MailHandler.fetchMail = function()
{
  console.log('Connection');
  imap.connect();
};

//fetchMail();

module.exports = new MailHandler()
```

Comment: Thank you :)
How yould I then call the `fetchMail()` function inside `app.js`?

Comment: Easy: mail.fetchMail()

Comment: I do not think so. Since that when you export the MailHandler module, you create a instance of itself. This instance is created by calling `imap.once('ready', function(){});` which is triggered when `imap.connect()` is done. I think there is something not right in this approach. But I may be wrong, could you explain?

Comment: Hmm. You'll have to find out what works for you. But what's for sure, when you do the require it will load whatever is inside, but it will not register the once event.